# How to control power to usb ports in a mac?

Tags: macos, usb, usb-3

Is it possible to "turn off" a usb port on an iMac using macOS? If yes how to do it?

I have seen other posts but they are windows machines.

iMac 21.5 late 2015 1080p
running Sierra.6 (All updates)

Comment: I doubt it, but I'll be watching this question in case someone else has a solution. By the way, there have been zillions of models of iMacs over the last 21 years, with lots of different USB host controllers and such, so you should probably Edit your question to specify your exact iMac model and macOS version.

Comment: @Spiff done ...